# sqlite3 to PG but "Undefined local variable or method `‘pg’' for Gemfile"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

Hi i want to migrate my ruby app from sqlite3 to Pg so i changed my gemfile file to something like that :

```
# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem ‘pg’
```

I changes my database.yml too but I still get an error when i try to run bundle install or rack db:create : Undefined local variable or method `‘pg’' for Gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Strings must be surrounded with `'` or `"`, but not with `‘` and `’`.